# Как сделать перенос строки?

Tags: php

Есть например код:

```
$a = 3;
$b = 1;
$op = "-";

switch ($op) {
  case '+':
    echo $a + $b ;
  case '-':
    echo $a - $b ;
  case '*':
    echo $a * $b ;
  case '/':
    echo $a / $b;
  case '%':
    echo $a % $b;
    break;
}
```

Перепробовал разные варианты - с кавычками, без, `</br>`, /n...Не могу понять как сделать перенос строки после каждого `echo` в `case` ?

Comment: а зачем делать после каждого? почему нельзя сделать один после switch?

Comment: ну вообще поместить логическую операцию в скобки и сконкатинировать со строкой, например `echo ($a + $b).'</br>' ;`  но тем не менее Ипатьев прав: зачем этот гемор, если можно после switch поставить перенос

Comment: Что такое `/n`?. Может вы ищете `"\n"`? --- должно быть имеено в двойных кавычках, если `\n` в одинарных работать не будет.

Comment: а как отловить ошибку деления на нуль, если $b = 0;

Comment: @Sven `if($b === 0) echo "Это число 0"`. Вообще почитайте про `try catch`. Можно еще так написать `case '/': if($b !== 0) echo $a / $b; else echo "Деление на 0";`

Comment: спасибо, понял!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
switch ($op) {
  case '+':
    $res=$a + $b ;
  case '-':
    $res=$a - $b ;
  case '*':
    $res= $a * $b ;
  case '/':
    $res=$a / $b;
  case '%':
    $res=$a % $b;
    break;
}
echo $res.PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: а как отловить ошибку деления на нуль, если $b = 0;

Comment: <code>  case '/':
    $res=$a / $b;</code>

Comment: заменить на case'/': if (b!=0){$res=$a/$b;}else{$res='ERROR';} break;

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Answer (score 1):

Или

```
echo '<br />';
```

или

```
echo "\n";
```

или

```
echo PHP_EOL;
```

(обратите внимание на двойные кавычки в последнем примере)

И кстати, `break` нужно добавлять после каждого условия

Comment: а если я хочу чтоб у меня все операторы выполнились с перенесом строки только

Comment: @Sven не понял, что Вы хотите?

Comment: Вы написали: И кстати, break нужно добавлять после каждого условия. А я пишу что мне ж надо чтобы все кэйсы вывелись.

Comment: @Sven ну так ставьте как я вам сказал в комментарии `echo ($a + $b).PHP_EOL;`  для всех кейсоф

Comment: @Sven Какое-то дикое желание. Ну если хотите, то да, `break` не нужен